# error compiling c program on r-pi raspbian

Tags: c, linux, makefile, raspberry-pi3

I have this code that compiles fine on my desktop, but when I try to compile it on the raspberry pi, I get this error

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c main.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c fft.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c draw.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c table.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -c serial.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lm -lSDL_image -lfftw3 -lftdi `sdl-config --cflags --libs` main.o fft.o draw.o table.o serial.o -o main
```

> /usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `table' changed from 2048 in
>   table.o to 204 in
>   //usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-10.0.so
>   /usr/bin/ld: table.o: undefined reference to symbol 'table'
>   //usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-10.0.so: error
>   adding symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status makefile:6: recipe for target 'main' failed
>   make: *** [main] Error 1

I've tried reinstalling libpulse0 and made sure pulseaudio was installed, and I can find the libpulsecommon-10.0.so when I search for it on the pi. So I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jeremy. Please use "I" (in capital), instead of "i", when referring to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libpulsecommon has a global symbol named `table`, and your code (probably table.c) also has a public symbol with this name. The symbols are colliding when linking. Rename that variable/function on your code.